# Mysterious gray square outlines on certain desktop icons?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

Recently, my hand slipped on my mouse/keyboard and I accidentally increased the icon size. After resetting it and fixing them, I noticed these incredibly annoying small gray outlines around only certain desktop icons.

I have one third party program called 'Desktop Restore' that I use to save and restore icon layouts, but I have no reason to believe that it should have anything to do with it.

My question is: Is this something in Windows 7? If so, what is it there for and how can I turn it off?

Killing explorer.exe and restarting it doesn't fix the problem, not even rebooting...

[image: The gray squares of death...]

Comment: the web says that happens if the icon is scaled Up or down.  **pbergonzi** said to do this --> Right-click Desktop->View->Change Large icons to Medium icons or Small icons.

Comment: Ah! I just had to refresh that setting! Thanks a ton!

Comment: but ??? how come killing the explorer or rebooting didnt fix it?  could it be the icon cache needed a refresh?

Comment: 11.11.2011 !!!!

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MS technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/3a2c3814-ab1d-4a7b-bf6d-c825aedb2c5a) says that happens if the icon is scaled up or down.

Similar issues were fixed by refreshing the desktop by right-clicking on the desktop and choosing "show desktop" or "refresh"

If you have Windows 7, Pbergonzi from [Cnet](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6142_102-303008.html) suggests:

Right-click Desktop → View → Change Large icons to Medium icons or Small icons.

Answer (score 1):

Just Right-click Desktop->View->Change Large icons to Medium icons or Small icons then refresh the desktop and you are done.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question " I noticed these incredibly annoying small gray outlines around only certain desktop icons... Is this something in Windows 7? If so, what is it there for and how can I turn it off?" He already stated that he fixed the icon size after increasing them.

Answer (score 0):

Click desktop, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouse Wheel.

This is how most people (accidentally) get the box in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem occures when some of icon "producers" do not care to include 256x256 version of it into the *.ICO file so if you (ctrl+mousewheel) exceeds 128x128 ico version that gray outline will appear in your intended "oversization" :-D

[ORIGINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0csda.jpg)

But there is kind of problem to add extras into *.ICO file by "nonpaid" means...
I found **ICOFX 3** and used just trial for 30 days (I think that is enough time to modify a few icon files :-D)
---There you just open *.ICO file -go to "Image" -choose "Add New Image" -add the missing size (ussualy only those 256x256 are missing) -save it -you will probably will have to "reload" ICO file in shorcut properties.

[ICOFX 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mzia.jpg)

---Some icons you will have to **Extract from files** the ICOFX giving you this
option on first page when you run it, then add what is necessary and save it into ICO file and reload it in shorcut properties.

---PS: I would recomend to save modified ICO files as a new file rather than the old one, It should save a bit of your time.

---PS: you may play quite a lot with programs tools, but I was ok just with "Sharpen" Effect :-)

[MODIFIED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgwgv.jpg)

Thats it... Now just get rid of these shield-stupidities xD